# background-color doesn't fill up the whole thing

Tags: html, css

Even after setting the margin and padding on the body and html to 0, the background color on my header element doesn't fill up the whole top part of the website.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is my html and css

```
<body>
        <header>
                <h1>Test Website</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
                <div>
                        <h2 >Test Website</h2>
                </div>
        </main>
    <body>
```

```
    html, body{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Nunito, sans-serif, serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    header{
        background-color: rgb(3, 231, 231);
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving margin 0 to a parent element does not means that a child does not still have default, *browser-given*  margins.

Elements like H1, H2, P, etc...  inherit the document's **User Agent Stylesheet**, which for hystorical styling reasons are given by the browser those default margins. Or paddings, like for UL, OL, etc...

Set the `margin` to `0` to any such element.
Use `padding` instead - if you want to add space to your block-level elements.

Inspect in developer console to figure out which elements are given such a margin.

One nifty and quick ***CSS reset*** I use is:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
/* applies to all elements on the page */
/* and no, it's not slow. 2022. */
```

A quick rule of thumbs:
use `margin` if you really, really know what you're doing (like i.e: handling the position of a CSS `grid` or `flex` child element). Use paddings instead.
Use `box-sizing: border-box;` to change the box sizing model, so that, while using the cool paddings, you don't have to account in the elements width/height (will be subtracted automatically by the browser).

Find out more on each of those properties on MDN.

Additional reading on collapsing margins: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: You misrepresent the contents of that MDN Web Docs tutorial article. It provides information on how to successfully use margins; it does not make the case for "why to avoid margins at all cost".

Comment: @Sean thank you, you're right. But my point is clear anyways. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The top margin of the `<h1>` element is pushing the `<header>` element down. You can either set a `padding-top` on the header element, or remove the margin from the heading.

Read more about [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Answer (score -1):

That is caused by the margin on you `h1` element.

Try adding this to your CSS as well

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```